# Change CSS values with jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

there.

So, I'm already using [Masonry jQuery Plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/) to make a Image Gallery Mosaic. Ok, the script works "fine", but when I load the page the images CSS alignment is wrong, or not working. See:

[image: screenshot]

However, if I press CTRL+SCROLL, or CTRL++/CTRL+-, the script works:

[image: screenshot]

Why? How I can fix it?

My JS:

```
    $(function(){
        var $container = $("#galeria");
            $container.masonry({
            itemSelector : 'li',
            columnWidth : 200
            });
    });
```

My CSS:

```
.organizar-galeria{ width: 100%; }
.organizar-galeria ul li{ width: 200px; }
.organizar-galeria ul li img{ float: left; width: 100%; }
#galeria{ width: 100%; float: left; padding: 5px 0px 10px 0px; }
```

My HTML:

```
       <div id="galeria">
        <div class="organizar-galeria">
        <?php if($GalleryDAO->countFetch['qntFotos'] == 0 AND $UserDAO->getUid() == $_SESSION['uid']) { ?>

        <p>Parece que você ainda não tem nenhuma foto. Se o dia estiver legal, que tal tirar uma?</p>
        </div>

    <?php } else { ?>

        <ul>
            <?php while($GalleryDAO->data = $GalleryDAO->query->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )):
                $var = getimagesize($GalleryDAO->getImageThumb()); ?>
                <li>
                    <?php if( $UserDAO->getUid() == $_SESSION['uid'] ): ?>
                        <a id="<?php echo $GalleryDAO->getImageId(); ?>" class="remover" href="#" >X</a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <a id="pictures"rel="group1" title="<?php echo $GalleryDAO->getLegenda(); ?>" href="<?php echo $GalleryDAO->getImageURL(); ?>" target="_blank">
                        <img class="excluirimg" <?=$var[3];?> src="<?php echo $GalleryDAO->getImageThumb(); ?>" alt="Imagem de <?php echo $UserDAO->getNome(); ?>" /></a>

                </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I already try with ***window.load*** and ***document.ready***.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the HTML of your page as well?

Comment: Of course, @Corey. See the main post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know masonry, but maybe your function executes too early.

Did you try the following, which is designed for image-loading:

```
$(function(){
    var $container = $('#galeria');
    $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
         $container.masonry({
              itemSelector : 'li',
              columnWidth : 200
         });
    });
});
```

Best of Luck,
Robson

Comment: Hello, Sunny. Thanks for your entry, but without success. I already try it one time.